# How to create a linked list using JSF2

Tags: java, jsf-2

What I want to do is not a simple linked list, but the design is very similar to it, so I asked the question like this just to make things simpler to explain.

The application I´m working on has a certain domain object that can be created by a user in a particular page. This newly created instance may or may not have a reference to another instance of the same class. Such another instance will be created in the very moment the first one is being created, which means, I´m not linked my under creation object to a previous existing one, but to one that is being created at the very moment it's being linked to.

The domain class is something like this:

```
class MyItem {
  private String name;
  private MyItem next;

  // getters and setters
}
```

The user wants a page where it's possible to set a name to a new instance of `MyItem` and eventually click a button to add the next item. In response to this click, a new line must be shown right below the first instance with a field to fill in the name of the next item and another button to eventually add a third item. The process can continue until we have a big number of instances, all connected to each other from the first to the last item. This is the so called linked list of the question.

When the user clicks the save button, many instances should be persisted at once.

How should I approach this use case in a JSF 2 application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Creating a linked list in JSF" sounds like a design smell. You should first iron out your domain model problem outside of what is just supposed to be a web application framework, and then plug in your working solution to the JSF framework. That or you're not explaining your problem clearly enough

Comment: @kolossus: I believe the problem is well explained, but if you have questions, do ask them. The design of a series of instances linked as a linked list doesn´t hurt any domain design good practices, so I can´t notice any smells here, unless your are saying that such a domain design can´t be supported by JSF2. Is that what your are saying? In this case, what design would be a better one?

Comment: So I did understand you correctly then. So what I'd recommend(again): your data structure/hierarchy should not be bound to a web application framework. Imagine you're not looking for a linked list. Imagine it's a vanilla list. Would you be looking for a web application-bound solution to implementing a list or would you develop your data structure *independently* of the web application framework and dropping it in your web app? Theoretically, bean injection (via JSF's injection or CDI) could possibly handle your requirement, but the question is, *should you*?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question but unless you're looking specifically to harness the nuances of JSF's bean handling (bean lifecycle, injection restrictions/limitations, scoping etc) to your   model design, JSF is not the right tool for you. Try CDI instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts (and no answer from the community), my only conclusion is that JSF2 does not support the idea of handling a linked list as a linked list. I kept my domain design as it is (because it is correct) but my managed bean had to work on array list created from the original linked list.

So, what I did was to create a `List<MyItem>` and implement the managed bean to work on a simple list of objects. Then, in the final moment, just before persisting all the instances I run over the list linking one item to the next, effectively creating the chain of the objects.

Of course, I have to trust that the order of the items in the intermediary (array) list is the order that the instances must be linked, but using `@SessionScoped` on the managed bean that was not a problem.